# Best data set for truth table to compute and reduce Sum of Products in C#

Tags: c#, boolean-expression, truthtable, boolean-algebra

so im trying to create a truth table in C# so that i can preform some boolean algebra on it. it is suppose to be a three variable truth table with 8 rows. so far right now im trying to use a string array of an array to input the truth table.

```
string[][] truthTable = new string[8][];
            truthTable[0] = new string[2] { "1" , "000"};
            truthTable[1] = new string[2] { "0", "001" };
            truthTable[2] = new string[2] { "0", "010" };
            truthTable[3] = new string[2] { "0", "011" };
            truthTable[4] = new string[2] { "0", "100" };
            truthTable[5] = new string[2] { "1", "101" };
            truthTable[6] = new string[2] { "1", "110" };
            truthTable[7] = new string[2] { "1", "111" };





            for (int i = 0; i < truthTable.Length; i++)
            {
                // print out strings  that have "1 as first element"
                if (truthTable[i].GetValue(i) == "1" )

                {
                    Console.WriteLine(truthTable[i]);

                }

            }
```

what I want to do right now is print out the arrays that have "1" as there first element. the console out put should be something like "1""000" for the first array for example, and it should only print the other three arrays that have "1" as well. but right now it gives me an out of bounds error and doesn't print anything.

Is this a good way to get started with a truth table to compute the sum of products  or is there a better way to implement it in C#?

Comment: should be `if (truthTable[i].GetValue(0) == "1"` . You have `i` in `GetValue` which is going to be out of bounds when i > 0

Comment: it solves the out of bounds problem but all it prints is System.String[] 4 times, which is better than what i had before, but how do i print out the "000" "101" etc?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(truthTable[i][1]);` prints the item at index 1 of array i. The default implementation of `ToString()` for objects just outputs the name of the type unless overridden. Primitive types, like the strings in the array, output their actual value as string.

Comment: Thanks so much! this works, but in your opinion, do you think this is a good way to implement a truth table? if you don't know thats fine.

Comment: It depends on your use case, as they can range to be quite complex. As the other poster mentioned, a Dictionary or HashSet might be a better fix. If you're looking to jump into the deep end, check out [this implementation of TruthTable](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Truth_table#C.23)

Answer (score 1):

One simple implementation would be to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.  The `string` key would hold your three variable values, and the second `string` value would hold the corresponding truth value:

```
var truthTable = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "000", "1" },
    { "001", "0" },
    { "010", "0" },
    { "011", "0" },
    { "100", "0" },
    { "101", "1" },
    { "110", "1" },
    { "111", "1" },
};

foreach (var keyValue in truthTable)
{
    // print out strings that have value of "1"
    if (keyValue.Value == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
    }
}
```

Though perhaps more in keeping with the domain of interest, you might consider just using a `Tuple` of `bool`s for the instead of a `string` for the variables key, and a `bool` instead of a `string` for the value:

```
var truthTable = new Dictionary<Tuple<bool, bool, bool>, bool>
{
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(false, true, false), true },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(false, true, true), false },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(false, false, false), false },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(false, false, true), false },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(true, true, false), false },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(true, true, true), true },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(true, false, false), true },
    { new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(true, false, true), true },
};

foreach (var keyValue in truthTable)
{
    // print out strings that have true value
    if (keyValue.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
    }
}
```

### Update:  using Linq for `Dictionary`

You can roughly approximate the `Dictionary` as a `List` of `KeyValuePair` tuples.  This means you can use all the Linq functionality available to any `Collection` -- e.g. the above `foreach` loop could use the `Where` Linq extension method and be simplified to the following:

```
// print out strings that have true value
var trueKeyValuesList = truthTable.Where(kv => kv.Value).ToList();
foreach (var keyValue in trueKeyValuesList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Key);
}
```

In this example, `trueKeyValuesList` is just that -- `List<KeyValuePair<Tuple<bool, bool, bool>, bool>>` (I <3 `var` :P ).  If just wanted a list of the `Tuple` values, you could use the `Select` Linq method (which behaves similarly to python's `map`) together with `Where`:

```
// print out strings that have true value
var trueValueKeys = truthTable
    .Where(kv => kv.Value)
    .Select(kv => kv.Key)
    .ToList();
foreach (var boolTuple in trueValueKeys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(boolTuple);
}
```

Comment: Hey Bondolin sorry for the  late reply, but this works really well! question though, I want to start doing boolean operations on all the tuples that are printed in the foreach loop. im thinking that putting those into a new list and then breaking the tuples apart will allow me to do this. but how do I add them to a list?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will try this out.And just to note, the main reason why im doing this is to be able to reduce the Sum of Products of the truth table. if you have any tips on that, id appreciate it. again thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, So  I followed your advice and its pretty good so far, but I've ran into a road block. im trying to reduce the duplicates in the `trueKeyList`  by doing `var reduced1 = trueKeyList.Distinct().ToList();` but its not removing any of the duplicates. any help with  this? by the way im using  string tuples, kinda of like a combination of your first and second option.

Comment: Well, at the point you are calling `Distinct` on it, `trueKeyList` is just a `List` of the string tuples; which are of course going to all be different, as they have been from the start, so I am a little unsure as to what you're trying to get at there?

Comment: here is an example of the tuples i have `{new Tuple <string,string,string>("A","!B","!C"),true },{new Tuple <string,string,string>("A","!B","C"),true },`   when we add them to the list and print them out there will be two "A"s in the list and two "!B"s in the list, im looking to remove the duplicates so that only 1 A and 1 !B remains. is this possible?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I think at this point that may be sufficient basis for a separate question.